# On trying to access a key in a dict I get 'KeyError'

Tags: python

I am unable to access some values in the dictionary like SID, RID and Active(Present inside 'Data').

```
{  
   "response":{  
      "Status":0,
      "AsOfDate":"2018-11-22T18:22:48.7719635Z",
      "ServiceName":"API",
      "Version":"1.0.6836",
      "Data":[  
         {  
            "UserName":"Automation",
            "Name":" USER",
            "Company":"SALE",
            "LastName":"USER",
            "Entitlements":{  
               "MAccess":true,
               "EAccess":true,
               "CAccess":true,
               "TP":true,
               "TQ":true,
               "Active":false,
               "TZ":true,
               "C":true
            },
            "AltEmail":null,
            "Status":"A",
            "RID":"111111",
            "IsActive":true,
            "Name":"AUTOMATION",
            "SID":"qYcuYD3DABU9ul2Rzg",
            "WhiteListed":true,
            "Email":"automation.user@something.com",
            "Phone":"1234512345"
         }
      ],
      "EndTime":"2018-11-22T18:22:48.7719635Z",
      "StartTime":"2018-11-22T18:22:48.7719635Z",
      "Total":1
   }
}
```

I am relatively new to python this is what i tried but i kept getting key error. Please suggest

```py
json_obj = json.loads(res.content)
print(json_obj)
for p_id, p_info in json_obj.items():
    print("\nPerson ID:", p_id)
    for key in p_info:
        print(key + ':', p_info[key])
        print('@@@@@@@@@@',p_info['Active'])
        print('@@@@@@@@@@',p_info['RID'])
```

Comment: show the complete error message

Comment: `p_info['Active'] is not a member on the root of that json object.  It's a member of the inner `Data` object.  Instead of `p_info['Active']`, you probably want `p_info['Data']['Active']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out, it's gross code but it does what you want:

```
my_dict = {  
   "response":{  
      "Status":0,
      "AsOfDate":"2018-11-22T18:22:48.7719635Z",
      "ServiceName":"API",
      "Version":"1.0.6836",
      "Data":[  
         {  
            "UserName":"Automation",
            "Name":" USER",
            "Company":"SALE",
            "LastName":"USER",
            "Entitlements":{  
               "MAccess": True,
               "EAccess": True,
               "CAccess": True,
               "TP": True,
               "TQ": True,
               "Active": True,
               "TZ": True,
               "C": True
            },
            "AltEmail": None,
            "Status":"A",
            "RID":"111111",
            "IsActive": None,
            "Name":"AUTOMATION",
            "SID":"qYcuYD3DABU9ul2Rzg",
            "WhiteListed": None,
            "Email":"automation.user@something.com",
            "Phone":"1234512345"
         }
      ],
      "EndTime":"2018-11-22T18:22:48.7719635Z",
      "StartTime":"2018-11-22T18:22:48.7719635Z",
      "Total":1
   }
}

for value in my_dict.values():
    for key, val in value.items():
        if key == 'Data':
            print(key)
            for x, y in val[0].items():
                if x == 'Entitlements':
                    print(x)
                    for z, v in y.items():
                        print('-', z, v)
                else:
                    print('-',x, y)
        else:
            print(key, val)
```

And the output

```
Status 0
AsOfDate 2018-11-22T18:22:48.7719635Z
ServiceName API
Version 1.0.6836
Data
- UserName Automation
- Name AUTOMATION
- Company SALE
- LastName USER
Entitlements
- MAccess True
- EAccess True
- CAccess True
- TP True
- TQ True
- Active True
- TZ True
- C True
- AltEmail None
- Status A
- RID 111111
- IsActive None
- SID qYcuYD3DABU9ul2Rzg
- WhiteListed None
- Email automation.user@something.com
- Phone 1234512345
EndTime 2018-11-22T18:22:48.7719635Z
StartTime 2018-11-22T18:22:48.7719635Z
Total 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access by accessing the json load path directly

```
p_info['response']['Data'][0]['Entitlements']['Active']
p_info['response']['Data'][0]['RID']
p_info['response']['Data'][0]['SID']
```

Comment: `Data` has only one item in the list. `['Data'][1]` would throw an IndexError

Comment: Correct, Updated the index